# Is there anyway to adjust the video in the center of screen using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to add a gif as a background to a video.
So the gif will take the whole space of the area while the video will be in center.

I am using this command but it's not working very well. it's just cropping the top and left hand side of the video while the bottom and right hand side of the video are still stretched to the whole space.

```
ffmpeg -ss 6 -i clip.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i b.gif -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w-2*28:in_h-2*25[base];[base][1:v]overlay=15:H-h-25:shortest=1" -codec:v libx264 out.mp4
```

This command should do what i need but there are three problems with it.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -vf "movie=bg.mp4:loop=200,hue=s=0[bg];[in]setpts=PTS/2,scale=iw/2:-1,pad=iw+20:ih+20:10:10:color=yellow[m];
```

1. It's adding a Yellow box around the video, which i don't want to
   add.
2. It's increasing the speed of video and audio, like fast forwarding.
3. Output video gets paused after 10,15 seconds while music is still
   playing in the background until the length of the video.

Is there any way to fix any of these commands.

Comment: What's the resolution of the gif and the video?

Comment: the resolution of the gif is H:400 and W:296 same for the video.

Comment: @Gyan Any idea about the cause of issue?

Comment: If both files are the same resolution, the top layer will completely cover the bottom layer and overlay has no meaning.

Comment: ok, but is there any other way to get something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yph83IzlHcE    background in gif and video playing at normal speed? it would be a huge favor if you guide me towards the correct path.

Comment: can you add some pictures to explain the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -ss 6 -i clip.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i b.gif -filter_complex "[1:v]hue=s=0[base];[0:v]scale=iw/2:-1[vid];[base][vid]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1" -codec:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4`

I've kept the `-ss 6` so your main video and its audio will start from 6 seconds of the input file.

Comment: can i drag this value to adjust it according to my needs?

Comment: Which value? `ss`? Yes.

Comment: Yes, the value of ss. I will try it Thank you so much.